# email sending via wso2 identity server fails

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server 5.9.0 on my linux machine.
I am getting the error below while doing account creation.

I get message Email sent successfully, but at backend it throws error after some time and the mail is never received.

[2020-02-15 13:09:22,241] [725c9824-a414-44f4-9b4f-e5f8da8db48c] ERROR

> {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} - Event
>   dropped at Output Adapter 'EmailPublisher' for tenant id '-1234',
>   Error in message format, Exception reading response
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;   nested
>   exception is:
>           java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2460)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:1699)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:744)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSender.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:306)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:126)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:106)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2440)
>           ... 13 more

I already made changes in output-event-adapters.xml and axis2.xml for smtp details.

Any help on this?

output-event-adapters.xml configuration is as below:
    
        
        noreply@xyz.com
        noreply@xyz.com
        
        ABC.XXX.XXX.XXX
        25
        true
        false
        
        8
        100
        20000
        10000

Comment: Looks like the server details are not correct or there is some problem getting the response from it (ports blocked, firewall. etc) as the error is 'Connection timed out (Read failed)'

Comment: Have you done any changes in email templates or EmailPublisher.xml file. You don't need to configure in both output-event-adapters.xml and axis2.xml can you share the configurations also check on your smtp server. Refer to this documentation for detailed instructions: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/enabling-notifications-for-user-operations/

Comment: @didiz ports are opened on firewall as i am able to send the mail via mailx command and mail is successfully recieved too. But the same doesnot work when wso2 dashboard sends confirmation mail for a new account creation confirmation or a password reset mail.

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga I didnt change nything in EmailPublisher. Also I tried with changing only in output-event-adapters.xml and not in axis2.xml, but it throws the same exception every time.

Comment: Do your smtp server amap@accenture.com  "Allow less secure apps" to access?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is blocked by google. Refer to this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Email+OTP)

> If you are using Gmail account you have to on "Allow less secure apps"
>   in your account.

For more info refer [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)